# How to make only one consumer for redis message listener in spring boot 3 and spring data redis?

Tags: java, spring-boot, redis, spring-data-redis

I am using spring boot 3 with spring data redis with functionality like this example [example](https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-redis/) . My solution is deployed in kubernetes cluster in multi pods configuration. I am producing a message from 1 pod and consuming on another pod. (I mean I want to have this behaviour 1 producer will produce message and only 1 will consume the message and delete it) However, I want only one pod to consume the message but right now I can see all pods are consuming same message at same time. How do I restrict this behaviour?

I want only one pod to consume the message but right now I can see all pods are consuming same message at same time. How do I restrict this behaviour?

Comment: What you want is so called consumer groups: https://redis.io/docs/data-types/streams-tutorial/#consumer-groups 
But all consumer in the same group and only one will process the message. 
This question should point you to the right answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61465222/how-to-use-consumer-groups-with-spring-data-redis-for-redis-streams-keep-gettin